# Git out of sync - Pulling not getting changes I see on the repo

Tags: git, github

I have 2 sites that were puling from a git repo. Something has happened and I can not sync my production site with the git repo.  There are changes there, but I am not getting anything.

How can I force the pull from git?  I don't want to loose anything on my production server, but I do need the updates that are on git?

Comment: Maybe the changes are on another branch? Have you tried manually merging the changes? Do you get an error? If so, which one?

Comment: I'm a git newbie for more than anything basic.  When I do get branch on my prod server I see * master  nothing else.  How man I force the merge without losing the changes I have on prod

Comment: What happens if you do a `git pull` on your server? Any errors? You need to give more details, otherwise it's just shooting into the dark …

Comment: Thank you.  No errors at all.  I get the message Already up-to-date.

Comment: What output does `git log origin/master..master` give? Already up to date normally indicates that you have all changes of the remote. But we should probably take this (longer) discussion to the [chat].

Comment: I've created a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61626/git-out-of-sync-pulling-not-getting-changes-i-see-on-the-repo) to discuss this question. Feel free to join!

Comment: Actually can't talk in the room.  :\

Comment: Did you try git status  any untracked files are there and check git remote -v command once

Comment: origin  git@github.com:mysite/mysite.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:mysite/mysite.git (push)